# Searching for a second order ODE whose solution is bell shape (Gaussian function)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, gaussian

I'm studying a nonequilibrium dynamics of a stochastic system. I found that in mean-field approximation the numerical solution resembles a bell shaped function (Gaussian function) with is zero at initial time, then reaches its maximum and finally decays to zero. I was wondering if there exist a second order ODE whose solutions are smooth and resemble Gaussian curves.  I know that one can get the ODE satisfies by a Gaussian function just deriving it twice. But this is not the point.  I'm interested in a general ODE which exhibits solutions which have similar behaviour of Gaussians. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "zero at initial time" doesn't much resemble a Gaussian.

Comment: You should better explain which features of the Gaussian you want. Possibly, attach a sketch, with care about the slopes and curvatures.

Answer (score 2):

The SDE (Stochastic Differential Equation) $dx_t = dW_t$ has a probability density function $p(x,t)$ that satisfies the PDE (partial differential equation) 
$$
\frac{\partial{p(x,t)}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2{p(x,t)}}{\partial{x^2}}
$$ 
(aka the heat equation), whose solution is the Gaussian function you described (with variance being time $t$),
$$
p(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}
$$
Note that the intial condition is a delta distribution, e.g. $\infty$ at origin and 0 at rest of the $x$ axis.

More generally, there is a class of stochastic processes (or SDEs) called [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process)
Maybe you can start from the Wiki page [Wave Equation/Brownian Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Brownian_motion) and go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much! You spared me a lot of time.

Comment: @Caute You are welcome! I also just started to learn SDE. Do you have any reference on the " nonequilibrium dynamics of a stochastic system" you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Hi, yes, it comes from the first order  differential system studied here https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2020.00010/full

Comment: @Caute Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Well, start with a solution that "resembles a Gaussian" and find an ODE that has that solution.

For example, if $y = \exp(-f(x)^2)$, then $y$ satisfies the second order differential equation $$y'' + 2 f(x) f'(x) y' + 2 (f'(x)^2 + f(x) f''(x)) y = 0$$